# Concatenate string variable in lua when using io.popen command

Tags: lua, concatenation

I want to concatenate this string called `test` inside the URL but it doesn't seem to work:

```
test = "1.1.1.1"
local geoip = io.popen("wget -qO- 'https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/' .. test  .. '":read():match'"name":"(.-)"')
print(geoip)
```

I got this error:

```
lua: hello.lua:3: ')' expected near ':'
```

I also tried doing like this way but I got the same error:

```
test = "1.1.1.1"
command = "wget -qO- https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/" .. test
local geoip = io.popen(command:read():matchname":"(.-)"')
print(geoip)
```

The url should append the test string. Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Fix your quotes and parentheses: `local geoip = io.popen ("wget -qO- 'https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/" .. test .. "'"):read ():match '"name":"(.-)"'`.

Comment: OMG... i feel so dumb missed that one bracket (the compiler even told me that but i didn't realized which bracket coz i had it on the end). would you write this answer in the answer section? I will accept it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix your quotes and parentheses; your `test` is inside a string literal and `read` and `match` are inside `io.popen` call:

```lua
local geoip = io.popen ("wget -qO- 'https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/" .. test .. "'"):read ():match '"name":"(.-)"'
```